# Instagram API: user feeds returning an html 404 page

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Recently, don't know since when, when requesting an Istagram user feed via PHP (or just hit the URL via browser) i recieve a 404 error page ... in html:

For instance, compare:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/bigbangtheory_cbs/media/recent/
(404 error page, html)

To:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nerd
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351
(json feed / error message if not authenticated)

Anyone else is experiencing the same problem? Any change happened recently in the Instagram API i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `user-id` not `user-name`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID`

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1532488534/media/recent/?client_id=

Comment: its asking access_token. i m getting this error if using `client_id` and `user-id`. `{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}`

Comment: @PrabuGuna they have updated the API so you must now use access token for all end points.

Comment: Actually, with the user-id and the access_token I experience the same behavior: a 404 HTML page for the API request (server side with php). Anyone else facing this problem?