# PHP instagram API request returns a 404

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to work with the Instagram API and their dreadful documentation!

All I want to do is query a users recent posts and have my PHP file return the JSON as a response but I am getting a 404 error returned.

I have authorized my application and have a relevant access token.

```
<?php
$access = 'access token';
$user = "username";

$data = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user/media/recent/?access_token=$access");

// SET JSON HEADER (TO DO)
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API: user feeds returning an html 404 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660603/instagram-api-user-feeds-returning-an-html-404-page)

Comment: Can you provide access token and user for test?

Answer (score -2):

It works with `user-id` not `user-name`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID`

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1532488534/media/recent/?client_id=

Comment: You said it duplicate and you copy answer from that post? Equity?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Yes, I am result-oriented, not equity-focused